# android app restart after calling onDestroy

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I am trying to terminate the application, but the problem is that onDestroy() is called and after that application(same activity) is restarted.

Can you please advice me what could be the reason for this?

Please bear with me I am newbie in android dev.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MainViewModel mainViewModel;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;


    @Override
    public void sendBroadcast(Intent intent) {
        super.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        /*int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        */


        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;/*
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;*/

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initDataBinding();
        EpgScreenService epgScreenService = new EpgScreenServiceImpl();
        //epgScreenService.firstShow();

    }

    private void initDataBinding() {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        mainViewModel = MainViewModel.getInstance(this);
        binding.setMainViewModel(mainViewModel);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 100ms
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        }, 1200);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

//        Toast.makeText(this,event.getKeyCode() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_X){

            startActivity(new Intent(this,EpgActivity.class));

        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Q){
            mainViewModel.stopPlayer();
            //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            //finish();

            int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


/*

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("PAUSED");

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
    }
*/

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("RESSUMED");
        mainViewModel.setupPlayer();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("DESTROYING");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/is-quitting-an-application-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: add your activity code please

Comment: Remove the call to System.exit(0); after killing the process.

Comment: Why not swap those three lines for 'finish();' to close the activity properly?

Comment: Well, it does not kill the app. if I call finish() it will restart the app; if i call kill PID it will restart the app; onDestroy is called i see System.out message but it has been restarted.

Comment: I have managed to finish main Activity, but splash has been called after MainActivity is finished. Also I have added android:noHistory="true" to Manifest file. =(

Comment: You should never use **System.exit(0)**.  It has undefined side effects.